# Two binomial expansions of a fractional power of z+w as multivalued functions

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

Let's treat $z^{1/T}$ and $w^{1/T}$ as multivalued complex functions.
Then, **what does $(z+w)^{1/T}$ exactly mean**?

We have two ways to interprate $(z+w)^{1/T}$:
$$I=\sum_{i}\binom{1/T}{i}z^{1/T}z^{-i}w^i$$ and
$$II=\sum_{i}\binom{1/T}{i}w^{1/T}w^{-i}z^i$$.

My question: when viewed as multivalued functions, are the above two series the expansions of the same (multivalued) function on different domains?

Moreover, if we interpret multivalued functions $z^{1/T}$ and $w^{1/T}$ as holomorphic functions on the universal covering of $(\mathbb{C}^2,0)$, how to interpret $(z+w)^{1/T}$?

Comment: domain of convergence is |w/z|<1 for I and |z/w|<1 for II